# How to add a secondary cluster to an already existing AWS RDS Aurora Postgres using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am having a hard time figure out the terraform equivalent for a aurora postgres secondary cluster. I have a terraform resource aws_rds_cluster which we used and created a regional cluster and writer and reader instance using instance resource in one region.

I now have a requirement to add a secondary region and reader instance into it. basically exactly what is described here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/migrate-amazon-aurora-across-aws-regions-with-minimum-downtime-using-aurora-global-database/

How do I use that in terraform ?  I think what I am stuck is how to get "Secondary Cluster" added to another region. Appreciate help